# Relocate wordpress plugin output thats hooked into the content

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook, action

I am trying to relocate the position of the output generated by a review plugin for wordpress. The plugin hooks into the end of "the_content". I have found the filter which works to remove the output:

```
remove_filter('the_content', array( EDD_Reviews::get_instance(), 'load_frontend'));
```

Now I am going crazy trying to relocate the output to a new location. I have created a custom hook in my theme file:

```
function reviews() {
do_action('reviews');
}
```

The above hook outputs just fine to custom location in the theme files when passed a simple function. However the tricky part is getting the reviews and review form to display. I tried adding it back with this:

```
add_action('reviews', array( EDD_Reviews::get_instance(), 'load_frontend'));
```

This did not work. The full function I am trying to call is below. Any body have any ideas how I may call this via my new hook? I am rather stuck.

```
public function load_frontend( $content ) {
           global $post;

           if ( $post && $post->post_type == 'download' && is_singular( 'download' ) && is_main_query() && ! post_password_required() ) {
                ob_start();
                edd_get_template_part( 'reviews' );
                if ( get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
                     edd_get_template_part( 'reviews-reply' );
                }
                $content .= ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
           }

           return $content;
     }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok mostly figured this out after studying classes. If anyone else is looking to do this then remove the hook as below:

```
remove_filter('the_content', array( EDD_Reviews::get_instance(), 'load_frontend'));
```

The following line will then render the reviews and form anywhere you like:

```
<?php echo EDD_Reviews()->load_frontend( '' ); ?>
```